# How can I check if a web app is running for the first time on browser in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, web, web-applications

I am new with web API and angularjs.

I have a web app with login form. I have to check if the web-app is running first time in browser, but I don't know any way to do that.

Any way to check it using angularjs? Thanks in advance.

Comment: elaborate on the exact version of angularjs you're using to get a more detailed answer

Comment: @shaunhusain, Thanks for quick response.  I'm using angularjs v1.6.4

Comment: No problem posted a bit more detail below let me know if you can't work it out but should be able to include the angular-cookies.js and ngCookies dependency on your main module then can use it to put or get cookies (the capability of the built in service hasn't been that great in the past so be sure to check specific docs for your version of angular/cookies module or alternatively look for third party services/modules)  It fails on here due to running in an iframe I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use cookies or local storage on the client side to store information in the browser to "know" if a user has been to the page.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies

Doesn't appear this is really updated but believe it is a usable solution if you want to use local storage instead: https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

```js
angular.module('cookiesExample', ['ngCookies'])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$cookies', function($cookies) {
  // Retrieving a cookie
  this.favoriteCookie = $cookies.get('myFavorite');
  if(this.favoriteCookie) {
    console.log('they have been here before oooo spooky')
  }
  // Setting a cookie
  $cookies.put('myFavorite', 'oatmeal');
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="cookiesExample" ng-controller="ExampleController as exc">
  {{exc.favoriteCookie}}
</div>
```